# overflow to the next div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a little hack to deal with the overflow. The js copy the the first div content and paste it to the second with a negative top offset.

```
.bg {
  position:relative;
  width:8.5in; height:11in;
  background-color:#306;
}
.content-wrap {
  position:absolute;
  width:8in; height:10.5in;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  background-color:#FFF;
  left:0.25in; top:0.25in;                         
}
.content {
  max-width:100%; max-height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#CCC;                           
}
```

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div id="mydiv1" class="content">           
            some html...<p></p>...<ul></ul>...<div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 


<div class="bg">
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div id="mydiv2" class="content"></div>      
    </div> 
</div>
```

```
var copy = $("#mydiv1").clone().css({
    "margin-top": '-'+ $("#mydiv1").height() +'px',
    "height": $("#mydiv1").height() * 2 +'px'});

$("#mydiv2").append(copy);
```

As you can see on the next image, it's not perfect. How to get a perfect result?

[image]

Comment: What effect are you trying to accomplish with the overflow?

Comment: nothing special, just put the overflow to the next div

Comment: No I meant what visual effect are you trying to accomplish because it would be easier to reposition the overflow text in the first div then send it to the second and try and compensate the difference

Comment: Oh you are trying to move the overflow past the blue and white bars into the next visual block

Comment: And actually now that I understand what you're trying to accomplish your problem is it is working perfectly meaning the parts of the words that are cut off in the top div are showing in the bottom div. your problem isn't the overflow not aligning correctly it's that it doesn't know it's cutting a line in half

Comment: There isn't really an easy fix for that. I imagine you don't simply want to make the first div bigger or make the first div scrollable instead?  Solving this the way you want to would require figuring out how much of the last line is cut in half and add that to the element bottom padding in your first div and subtract it from the top margin in your second div. in essence moving the cut line down to the second div.

Comment: but calculating that value would not be easy. (And it would have to be calculated otherwise a different sized screen would end up with another cut line) it might be easier to take the whole element that is overflowing (i.e. The paragraph) and send that to the next div. but splitting the multi line text element between two divs is hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the height of your div doesn't match the line-height of your text. Your line-height needs to be divisible by the height of the div. Try adjusting it so that the last line of the first box is flush with the bottom.

Comment: The problem is that the first div have not only paragraph in it...some ul, div...so adjusting the line-height will work even with those html elements?

Comment: It should work for all text content, just set it on the .content class and it should apply to all of it's children that don't have their own line-height property. If you want to be sure you can do something hacky like `.content * { line-height: 20px; }`

Comment: I'm not sure it will work, some html elements add some padding (like <ul>) but I think you found the problem...so I accept your answer